# Php mysqli update column using variable name

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to php and mysqli. I'm trying to update a column whose name is passed through a variable.

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE Table SET $columnname = $columnupdate WHERE user_id = ?");
```

Am I being a pleb or should this work?

Comment: what/where is the problem? what are the values of your variables?

Comment: `$columnupdate` should also only be prepared via `?`

Comment: Yep changed that, works now. Also forgot a semicolon somewhere...need coffee...Thanks.

Comment: can you please updtae which is the variable you want to update??

Comment: so what is the problem?